# Inhomogeneous heat equation with temperature dependent sink

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am trying to solve an inhomogeneous heat equation where the source term depends linearly on the temperature of the system.

$\partial_t u(x,t) - D \partial_{x,x}u(x,t) = -\gamma u(x,t) H(t) \delta(x)$

Where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function and $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta.

The initial condition is $u(x,0) = const.$

The domain of the problem is the entire real line.

At the boundary $\partial_x u(\pm \infty, t) =0 $.

I attempted to solve this equation in momentum space but have made little progress towards a solution. I can numerically solve this equation but I would really benefit from a closed form solution.

Are there any techniques that may be useful for find the solution?

Comment: I assume you mean a minus sign in the second derivative term. In any case the usual approach is to convert the forcing into a boundary condition instead.

Comment: What about a Fourier transformation ?

Comment: Assuming this is an initial value problem, would you make explicit the spatial domain?

Comment: The domain is the entire real line The initial condition is u(x,0) = const.

Comment: Does the $\delta(x)$ in the 'source term' mean there is some sort of heat production layer along the surface $x = 0$? If so, that would split the spatial domain naturally into $x < 0$ and $x > 0$, with a discontinuity at $x = 0$.